# How to send curl request after curl request with data from first request?

Tags: php, curl, request

I want to send  two curl requsts.
First:

```
function auth($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $s01 = strpos($html, 'Redirecting', 0);

    if ($s01 === false) {
        echo "Not Found";
        $found_url = '';
    } else {
        echo "Found ";
        if (preg_match('/<a href="(.+)">/', $html, $matches));
        $found_url = $matches[1];

        return $found_url;
    }
}
```

And second:

```
function auth1($found_url) {
    $ch = curl_init($found_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $found_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    $headers = array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',

    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $html;
    return $html;

}
```

I want to send  two curl requsts. After sending first requst I need to get $found_url from first request and send second request with it. How to implement this correctly? I know this maybe a stupid question, but I stuck with it.

Comment: Code looks ok to me, just move the `return` on first method out of the `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the first auth to return always something by either adding a return to your 'not found part' to return maybe null or empty, or by moving the return to outside of your if statement. Then the following code should work.

```
$foundUrl = auth($url);
if($foundUrl){
   $html = auth1($foundUrl);
}
```